# Windows 11 url shortcut icon not displaying url favicon.ico

Tags: windows, shortcut

I have a web app that I'd like to create a URL web shortcut. Chrome is my default browser. I've tried creating a file with the parameters below with the .url extension. The shortcut displays Chrome's default icon and not the URLs icon. I've tried removing the IconIndex and/or IconFile parameters thinking the shortcut might pick up the URL's favicon but it does not. I've tested dragging the URL from Chrome onto the desktop and the shortcut still displays Chrome's default icon. I've also dragged a chrome bookmark to the desktop and it still displays Chrome's default icon.

My task is to create a URL shortcut and have it display the URLs icon.

I'd rather not have to copy a DLL or ico locally to display an icon.

File parameters:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.bing.com
IconIndex=0
IconFile=https://www.bing.com/favicon.ico
```

Comment: Windows won’t use a url for that.

Comment: Do you know of some way to create a shortcut to web url and have it use a url to a ico file? I have a web app that I need to deploy and want to simply copy over the shortcuts to the client machines. Don't want to have to deal with copying over an ico file for the image.

Comment: you could use a progressive web app possibly